# Vertebrae looking bone found on beach in New Zealand

Tags: species-identification, zoology, anatomy, tissue, bone

I found this bone on a beach in New Zealand. Does anybody have any idea which part of the body or which animal it’s from?

[image]
[image]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: Are you looking to identify it beyond just being a vertebra? It's a vertebra for sure, but beyond that, it's hard to identify beyond "probably a large mammal", which for New Zealand would likely be some kind of whale or dolphin, unless it's something non-native like a cow.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. It would help if you could give some measurements for the vertebra — we can only get a very rough guess based on the hand size. My understanding is that the most probable answer for New Zealand is always going to be sheep, but I think these are too large ... I agree with kmm that these are likely to be from a marine mammal of some sort.

Comment: It would also help to know roughly where in NZ (e.g. Northland, BOP, West Coast, 'Naki, etc.), as the animals present vary quite widely from North to South and East to West.